# How to write Arial bold 12 text from 12 dpmm(300 dpi) a printer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

How to write Arial bold 12 text from 12 dpmm(300 dpi) a printer,
I am try this but not working 
 `^FT430,704^A0N,90,90 ^FH\^FD ARİAL Bold 12 ^FS`

Answer (score 2):

Zebra printers have built in fonts, I don't think Arial (bold) is one of them.  You can specify a built in font, or you can upload a font (see https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7891 ).

Check your printer's drive contents to find your uploaded font name, then use the ^A@ command to print with it:

```
^XA^FO50,50^A@N,50,50,E:ARI000.FNT^FDSAMPLE ARIALI^FS ^XZ
```